# draw: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: arrays, runtime-error, processing, draw

I'm making my very first text adventure game but keep getting an error thrown at me. I honestly have no clue what's going on or how to even start fixing the issue. I'll post my code and the error message I'm receiving exactly.

```
PFont computer; //creates a variable for the font to be used
int level = 0; //starting level
int branch = 0; //starting level

String[][] textOptions = new String[][]{
  {"Welcome to our text adventure. You are in a room.\n" //new line
  + "It looks like no one has been in here for years.\n"
  + "Would you like to look around? Y/N",""},

  {"You decide to look around the room.\n"
  + "You stand by your initial observation.\n"
  + "The room is covered in a thick layer of dust with cobwebs reaching out in every corner.\n"
  + "There are a few shelves, lined with decaying boxes and files. The terminal you are looking for is nowhere to be seen. \n"
  + "You are now in a hallway. There are two rooms to explore. L/R?",
    "You decide to leave this room. You are now in a hallway.\n"
  + "There are two rooms to explore. L/R?"},

  {"You decide to check the room to the right.",
   "You decide to check the room to the left."},

    };

void setup()
{
  size(1350,700);
  computer = createFont("computer.ttf",25);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  textSize(20);
  textFont(computer);
  text(textOptions[level][branch],10,25);
  fill(0,239,31);
}

void keyPressed()
{
  if(key == 'y')
  {
    println("Player is looking around.");

    if(level < 2)
    {
      level = level+ 1;
      branch = 0;
    }
  }
  else if(key == 'n')
  {
    println("Player decided to leave this room.");

    if(level < 2)
    {
      level = level+ 1;
      branch = 1;
    }
  }

{
    if(key == 'r')
  {
    println("Player has chosen the room to the right.");

    if(level < 3)
    {
      level = level+ 1;
      branch = 2;
    }
  }
  else if(key == 'l')
  {
    println("Player has chosen the room to the left.");

    if(level < 3)
    {
      level = level+ 1;
      branch = 3;
    }
  }
}
}
```

I keep getting the error code:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at sketch_171010c.draw(sketch_171010c.java:50)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2437)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1557)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:316)
```

and it appears to be highlighting the portion of draw that says textOptions[level][branch] but I still don't understand what this means or how to fix this issue whatsoever. Any help or input on how to literally do anything would greatly be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0):

You should get into the habit of [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your code so you understand exactly what it's doing.

The exception is caused by trying to access an index that an array doesn't have. Here's a simpler example:

```
String[] array = {"test"};
String x = array[100];
```

This code would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the array only has a single element, but we're trying to access index 100. That's what's happening in your code.

Now, **why** that's happening is going to require debugging your code. Step through it with a piece of paper and a pencil to track the value of the variables, or use the debugger that comes with the Processing IDE.

Comment: I've solved the error being thrown but now I'm just having the issue of the 2nd key input not being recognized? Like, my game only recognizes the Y or N input for the options, when I try to put L or R it doesn't progress.

Comment: @DesireeCenname It's still the same answer: you have to **debug** your code to understand exactly what's happening. Then if you get stuck, post a [mcve] instead of your whole project. Good luck.